# How to maintain old list values in dropdown?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath

I'm using infopath 2013 and share point 2013

In infopath form design I am using Drop down  field and bind values from share point list.

[image]

***Share point List***

[image]

I select India and submitted the form successfully. After submitting I change the Country list. Like

1. South Africa
2. Dubai

Old value India and USA Deleted.

Now If i click new document status drop down values will be South Africa, Dubai.

my Issue is If i open the submitted form before list value change. Status drop down values should be changed to south Africa.

But i need to maintain the old list value ( India) in drop down.

How to resolve this issue.

I try with create another view copy the status and goto View Properties select read only.

but value changed...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a seaprate field that will store the selected country. Set that field on submission. Use that field to display the selected country even the values from your dropdown change.